# Inserting multiple entries to database from generated checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, laravel

I apologize if this has been asked before, this is my first project using laravel and I couldn't find a similar question.

I am trying to insert into a database the values from a checkbox field, that has values generated from another database.

A snip from my form:

```
        @foreach($labourTypes as $id => $name)
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    {!! Form::checkbox("labour_types[]", $id) !!} {{$name}}
                </label>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

I am inserting data from this form into two different tables. I have the first tables data inserting, however the 2nd table needs data from these checkboxes, as well as data from the first table.

This is what I currently have in my controller:

```
    $labour_types = Input::get('labour_types');
    DB::table('employee')->insert([
        'id' => null,
        'employee_name' => $_POST['employeeName']
    ]);
    foreach($labour_types as $labour_type)
        DB::table('employee_labour_types')->insert([
            'id' => null,
            'labour_type_id' => 'labour_type[]',
            'employee_id' => null
        ]);
    }
```

The ID in the 2nd table is auto increment, but the employee ID comes from the auto incrementing ID in the first table. I am trying to do separate entries for the same employee, if they have different labour types.

For example in my 2nd table: (id = 1, labour_type_id = 1, employee_id = 1), (id = 2, labour_type_id = 2, employee_id = 1)
Can be generated from this form.

Thanks.

**EDIT: I have the data posting to the 2nd table, but currently with a null employee_id (as above) - I am now trying to find a way to post the employee_id to employee_labour_types table. This is 'id' from 'employee' table in the first insert. Is the only way to do this to query it and then add it?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working - for future similar questions, my solution:

My query:

```
$empid = DB::select("SELECT id AS \"Name\" FROM employee WHERE employee_name = '" . $_POST['employeeName'] . "'");
```

In my insert statement

```
    'employee_id' => $empid[0]->{'Name'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to use `$_POST` when using Laravel.  Also, you don't include the `[]` in the name when reading from that input in PHP.  To access the array, you would...

```
$labour_types = \Input::get('labour_types');
foreach($labour_types as $labour_type) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was actually just in the middle of editing my post when you replied this. I applied the changes - however I am now getting an error when trying to post the form: "Undefined variable: labourTypes" in my .php page that has the form

Comment: Undefined $labourTypes has to do with the data that you're sending. I guess you should be using $labour_types if you're passing it as the parameter name.

Comment: I just added the $labourTypes variable (which was in my get) to my post and added it to the return view and it seemed to fix my issue. I am just now trying to figure out how to query the ID from the first insert to insert it into the 2nd table